# How to remove dropdown aggregate menu from GNOME 3?

Tags: indicator, gnome-shell

How to remove this one?

[image: Dropdown menu]

And put all stuff in the taskbar instead?

Comment: have you not yet tried dash to panel extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using the **[Extend Panel Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1201/extend-panel-menu/)** GNOME shell extension.

[image]

Read this to learn about installing and managing GNOME extensions: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481)